# Using jq to extract certain info from JSON file

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

I am extracting some info from my json files that are formatted like this:

```
{
    "name": "value",
    "website": "https://google.com",
    "type" : "money",
    "some": "0",
    "something_else": "0",
    "something_new": "0",
    "test": [
      {"Web" : "target1.com", "type" : "2" },
      {"Web" : "target2.com", "type" : "3" },
      {"Web" : "target3.com", "type" : "3" }, 
      {"Web" : "target3.com", "type" : "3" } 
    ]
}
```

I am aware that `jq -r .test[].Web` will output:

```
target1.com
target2.com
target3.com
```

but what if I only want to get the values with type is 3 meaning the output will only show target2.com and target3.com

Comment: Check your data again, what you're asking for doesn't make sense with that.  Each of the "test" items have different names.  How are we supposed to know what name to expect and for what type?  There is no pattern to it at all.

Comment: ahhh I made a mistake! I fixed the data.. I wante to get jq -r .test[].Web but only ones with type 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ jq -r '.test[] | select(.type == "3").Web' file.json 
target2.com
target3.com
target3.com
```

This passes the `.test[]` nodes to `select`, which filters its input using the `.type == "3"` selector. Then it selects `.Web` from the filtered list.

Comment: Would prefer the style `.test | map(select(.type == "3") | .Web) | .[]`, not expanding the array until the very last step.